# How to 'reproduce copyright` in an app?

Tags: licensing, bsd-license

> - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
>     notice, this list of conditions and
>     the following disclaimer in the
>     documentation and/or other materials
>     provided with the distribution.

The above is quoted from a BSD licensed COPYING file. How can I "reproduce the above copyright" when I distribute my app in binary form? Should I put the COPYING file content in some `Credit`/`About` screen of my app or what? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See for example how Apple does it.

On iOS you can reach a Copyright menu inside the settings menu. It's a rather long entry, listing all copyrights, including BSD licenses.

Answer (score 1):

yes, include it in the About screen. And/or include a copy of the file in the distribution directory of your application (or what some applications do, create a directory called "licenses" containing all such license files for every library/framework they use.